# I want to display the pdf file from sharepoint to dynamics 365 using iframe, but i am getting an error as sharepoint refused to connect

Tags: sharepoint-online, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

When i am trying to display the pdf file from sharepoint to dynamics 365,i am getting an error as sharepoint refused to connect.Can anyone help me out in solving this issue.

Comment: Could you provide more information regarding the error that SharePoint is returning?

Comment: When I am trying to view the pdf file which is in sharepoint online to dynamics 365 using file viewer, i am getting an error as sharepoint refused to connect.Except pdf files, document and other files can be viewed.Is there any way to solve this.